# Why can't Windbg find my XP machine when Kernel Debugging over Serial port

Tags: kernel, windows-xp, windbg

Host:

Windows 10 running windbg, Serial port on COM2, USB to serial cable

Target:

Windows XP SP2, Serial port on COM2, USB to serial cable

I'm trying to attach windbg to a physical windows XP machine to debug my driver but I'm not seeing the connection. I can see the debug option on boot because I've configured the boot.ini file of the target to enable debugging:

`multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect /debug /debugport=COM2 /baudrate=115200`

I've connected the two machines using two usb to serial cable and null modem cable in between. I've also tested to check that the serial connection is functional by using hyper terminal on both machines.

When using Windbg I see: [image]

I've tried CTRL+BREAK and issuing commands but I get nothing. What am I missing in order to be able to connect windbg to my XP machine?

Comment: I want to add an update: using a different XP machine which has a dedicated serial port, I'm able to connect the debugger. My Follow up question, is how to connect to my original target machine? The CPU has no native serial ports.

Answer (score 1):

- a) Try to use a slower speed the first time (you can always increase
  it later)
- b) Check the port settings of both system with device manager (boot your target in none debug mode).
- c) Windbg need to be startet first (Waiting for reconnect...) then start the target in debug mode

Comment: I've tried a) b) and c) Still have the same result. Could it that I'm using a USB to serial cable?

Comment: For driver development I use vmware sessions connected via named pipe serial port. Would this be an option?